# Custom form reloads in multiserver load balanced farm

Tags: modal-dialog, load-balancing, farm

I have my Web Application deployed in 2-3 environments and now it is deployed in production environment but it giving us a problem.

Wherever there is modal dialog, it keeps reloading intermittently.

The farm is multi-server with load-balancer.

I am unable to produce the error locally.

Comment: what did you try so far? why do you think that the problem is due to the load balancer?

Comment: thats what we are trying to find out. but no luck so far.